# How should I trigger ARM deployments

Tags: powershell, azure, continuous-deployment, azure-resource-manager, octopus-deploy

We are trying to establish a continuous deployment environment. Conflicted how to do ARM deployments.  Deploying all the resources as a group is much better them handling them individually.

ARM has a nice declarative syntax. We are telling what we intend to create" without having to write the sequence of programming commands to create it. Which is great but how should we run them ?

Two options come up to my mind

I.I could download the templates and use power shell.

II. Trigger using Azure automation

III. x

What is the best practice ?

Reference
Octopus integration from source code
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this as part of your CI/CD chain, you probably want to check in the templates and deployment scripts with your source code. That way, the definition of the infrastructure is kept with the code that's intended to run on it.

If this is part of some other workflow, it really depends on the workflow :)

Comment: I am at the stage of setting up the playground sub in Azure. After setting it up I will parameter it and than want to trigger this from the source code. Source code does not seem practical right now. Or can I integrate it with octopus?

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin check my answer

Comment: Tomas I have selected your route . Matter of fact is packing the projects into .deployproj format/template is good. We can deploy from Visual Studio and from Octopus. We need to test the templates in a playground.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using powershell\cli and just invoke the template from the uri, that is the easiest way of doing that (instead of downloading it). This can be run with anything that is capable of running a custom script task, or specific CI\CD systems that have steps to deploy ARM Template (VSTS\Octopus\probably something else)

I would advice against Azure Automation for that cause.

Also, I do suggest separate code from arm templates

Comment: What's the main benefit of separating code from the ARM templates?

Comment: you can have separate deployment\release cycles for actual application and arm templates